# unserialize php in goland

Tags: go, goland

I have a file with serialized array in PHP.
The content of the file locks like this

```
a:2:{i:250;s:7:"my_catz";s:7:"abcd.jp";a:2:{s:11:"category_id";i:250;s:13:"category_name";s:7:"my_catz";}}
```

The array unserialized is this

```
(
    [250] => my_catz
    [abcd.jp] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 250
            [category_name] => my_catz
        )

)
```

Now, i want to get the content of the file in GO, unserialize it convert it to an array.
In GO i can get the content of the file using

```
dat, err := os.ReadFile("/etc/squid3/compiled-categories.db")
    if err != nil {
        if e.Debug {
            log.Printf("error reading /etc/squid3/compiled-categories.db: ", err)
        }
    }
```

And unserialized it using github.com/techoner/gophp library

```
package categorization

import (  
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "github.com/techoner/gophp"
    "log"
    "errors"
)

type Data struct {  
    Website   string
    Debug   bool
}

func (e Data) CheckPersonalCategories() (int,string) {  
    if e.Debug {
        log.Printf("Checking Personal Categories")
    }
    if _, err := os.Stat("/etc/squid3/compiled-categories.db"); errors.Is(err, os.ErrNotExist) {
        if e.Debug {
            log.Printf("/etc/squid3/compiled-categories.db not exit: ", err)
        }
        return  0,""
    }
    dat, err := os.ReadFile("/etc/squid3/compiled-categories.db")
    if err != nil {
        if e.Debug {
            log.Printf("error reading /etc/squid3/compiled-categories.db: ", err)
        }
    }
    
    out, _ := gophp.Unserialize(dat)
    
    fmt.Println(out["abcd.jp"])
return  0,""
}
```

But I can't access to the array, for example, when I try access to array key using out["abcd.jp"] i get this error message

```
invalid operation: out["abcd.jp"] (type interface {} does not support indexing)
```

The result of **out** is

```
map[250:my_catz abcd.jp:map[category_id:250 category_name:my_catz]]
```

Comment: For starters, don't ignore any error coming from any Go function you call.  For all you know the unserialize command isn't even succeeding.  Next, show enough code to reproduce your example, with the serialized PHP data inside the code so we can test it ourselves.   Seems like it should be working so we need enough data to reproduce its behavior

Comment: Hi
I have edit the post to include the full function

Seams that is unserializing because the content of the file is
a:2:{i:250;s:7:"my_catz";s:7:"abcd.jp";a:2:{s:11:"category_id";i:250;s:13:"category_name";s:7:"my_catz";}} and the output is map[250:my_catz abcd.jp:map[category_id:250 category_name:my_catz]]

The problem is that i can't get the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Seams that is unserializing

Don't make assumptions about what is and isn't succeeding in your code.  Error responses are the only reliable way to know whether a function succeeded.  In this case the assumption may hold, but ignoring errors is always a mistake.  Invest time in catching errors and at least `panic` them - don't instead waste your time ignoring errors and then trying to debug unreliable code.

> invalid operation: out["abcd.jp"] (type interface {} does not support indexing)

The package you're using unfortunately doesn't provide any documentation so you have to read the source to understand that `gophp.Unserialize` returns `(interface{}, error)`.  This makes sense; php can serialize any value, so `Unserialize` must be able to return any value.

`out` is therefore an `interface{}` whose underlying value depends on the data.   To turn an `interface{}` into a particular value requires a type assertion.  In this case, we think the underlying data should be `map[string]interface{}`.  So we need to do a type assertion:

```
mout, ok := out.(map[string]interface{})
```

Before we get to the working code, one more point I'd like you to think about.  Look at the code below: I started it from your code, but the resemblance is very slight.  I took out almost all the code because it was completely irrelevant to your question.  I added the input data to the code to make a minimal reproduction of your code (as I asked you to do and you declined to do).  This is a very good use of your time for 2 reasons: first, it makes it a lot easier to get answers (both because it shows sufficient effort on your part and because it simplifies the description of the problem), and second, because it's excellent practice for debugging.  I make minimal reproductions of code flows all the time to better understand how to do things.

You'll notice you can run this code now without any additional effort.  That's the right way to provide a minimal reproducible example - not with a chunk of mostly irrelevant code which still can't be executed by anybody.

The Go Plaground is a great way to demonstrate go-specific code that others can execute and investigate.  You can also see the code below at https://go.dev/play/p/QfCl08Gx53e

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/techoner/gophp"
)

type Data struct {
    Website string
    Debug   bool
}

func main() {
    var dat = []byte(`a:2:{i:250;s:7:"my_catz";s:7:"abcd.jp";a:2:{s:11:"category_id";i:250;s:13:"category_name";s:7:"my_catz";}}`)
    out, err := gophp.Unserialize(dat)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if mout, ok := out.(map[string]interface{}); ok {
        fmt.Println(mout["abcd.jp"])
    }
}
```